# Python Базы Данных

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite3, asyncio

Работаю с большим количеством баз данных на python. Работа заключается в поиске совпадений в той или иной базе. Вопрос: Как можно улучшить, упростить код, который я указал ниже?

```
import aiosqlite
import asyncio

class DataBase:

    async def __aenter__(self):
        self.db = await aiosqlite.connect('Bases/mybase.db')
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *args):
        await self.db.close()

    async def information(self, phonenum: str) -> str:
        cursor = await self.db.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE phonenum == ?", (phonenum,))
        row = await cursor.fetchone()
        return row

async def content():
    async with DataBase() as db:
        cont = await db.information('phonenum')
        return cont

asyncio.run(content())
```

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает имеющийся код? Это должно быть в вопросе. Для одиночных запросов код норм. А для массовых нужно знать что вы и как конкретно запрашиваете. Если памяти достаточно, то проще считать всю базу в память и проверять/искать в памяти.

Comment: Вариантов много :) можно распараллелить через offset + много корутин закинуть в event_loop, использовать connection_pool, вам из какой сферы надо улучшать код?